# unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yet again, another one of these errors..

I've tried searching around to get this resolved before asking, but couldn't find anything that would fix this issue.

So I've got:(**Updated**)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $('.episodes').live('click',function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),
            width = 730,
            height = 645;

            if(id == 3){
                width = 635;
                height = 790;
            }                   

            ColdFusion.Window.create('Episode_'+id,'','/landing_pages/superhero/episode'+id+'.cfm',{width:width,height:height,center:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true});
        });
    });
</script>
```

I've tried escaping the **"text\/javascript"** and the **<\/script>**, but it'll either not work at all and not show the error anymore because it won't recognize it as a javascript statement or it will continue to throw the error.

Firebug is saying the problem is: `var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),`, but I'm not seeing where that could be a problem.

I was considering escaping the **/** in the create method at the bottom, but I wouldn't think it'd make a difference because it's showing the error is at the top.

Thanks!

**(Update)**
I've tried all of the answers with the semi-colon issue, and it didn't work. Didn't impact it whatsoever. Any other ideas?

I'm actually pasting this into a CMS and it's going through SQL and then outputting it in my article. I don't see why it would cause a problem, but I guess it's another thing to consider.

**UPDATED WITH FIX**
The error was the use of the single quotes. Had to change all of the single quotes to a double quote. Apparently that's something you've got to do when you're inserting it into the DB.

Final code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $(".episodes").live("click",function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("episode_",""),
            width = 730,
            height = 645;

            if(id == 3){
                width = 635;
                height = 790;
            }                   

            ColdFusion.Window.create("Episode_"+id,"","/landing_pages/superhero/episode"+id+".cfm",{width:width,height:height,center:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete error? Full message and stack trace if possible.

Comment: The problem could be another tag with an unclosed double quote around some attribute that occurs before the script.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand what you're asking. Why would you want to escape `text/javascript`? That's a standard constant. Adding characters there won't escape anything; it will just tell the browser that this isn't JavaScript -> the browser will ignore the `script` element with unknown content.

Comment: i wonder whether it could be the semi-colons....

Comment: Who or what is "it"? What is "problem"? Do you get an error message? If so, why did you omit it?

Comment: I'm trying a few different things now. I'm pretty sure my question was straight forward.. The exact error is "Unterminated String Literal". That's it.. It highlights the var id segment of code. I'll update in a second.

Comment: @Aaron, I tried escaping those because most people having this same error, had to do that to fix the error. That's why. Google the error and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means that one of the single quotes in `$('.episodes').live('click',function(){` isn't a single quote but something else (probably a back quote).

Try to replace all of them with double quotes (`"`) because the ASCII encoding only contains one double quote but three different single quotes ('´`).

Answer (score 5):

try using semicolons:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
            $('.episodes').live('click',function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),
                var width = 730,
                var height = 645;

                if(id == 3){
                    width = 635,
                    height = 790;
                }                   

                ColdFusion.Window.create('Episode_'+id,'','/landing_pages/superhero/episode'+id+'.cfm',{width:width,height:height,center:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true})
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: good answer. @Michael, I believe you got confused as to thinking you were populating an array, and not writing a regular function. Been there done that.

Comment: Haha, I had to laugh when I saw this - I totally missed the use of commas instead of semi-colons on the end. +1

Comment: actually, it would be enough to have a semicolon after `height` in the original code. Using a `comma` to separate variable declarations is just fine.

Comment: You definitely don't need the var in front of them all. You're declaring multiple variables and it's a valid approach. I will try closing everything out though.

Comment: @jAndy i fixed it. is it OK??

Answer (score 2):

The problem exists in

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),
    width = 730,
    height = 645
```

because it needs a semicolon at the end, not a comma.

```
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),
    width = 730,
    height = 645;
```

Same goes for everything else inside of

```
if (id == 3) {...
```

Comment: No, there shouldn't be a semicolon there, it's a comma separated list of declarations. There should be a semicolon at the end of the statement, i.e. after the three declarations.

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is wrong, javascripts uses a ; to terminate a statement

thats the correct solution

```
$('.episodes').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_', '');
    var width = 730;
    var height = 645;
    if (id == 3) {
        width = 635;
        height = 790;
    }
    ColdFusion.Window.create('Episode_' + id, '', '/landing_pages/superhero/episode' + id + '.cfm', { width: width, height: height, center: true, draggable: false, resizable: false, modal: true });
});
```

**Edit**

my bad, your syntax was right too.

Comment: You changed the declarations of `width` and `height` to just assignments, which changes their scope.

Answer (score 0):

When I check the code in JsLint, it doesn't complain about any unterminated strings, only that you omitted the semicolons at the end of each statement. That might however have some unexpected consequences, so it might very well be the reason for the error message.

Put semicolons at the end och each statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function(){
    $('.episodes').live('click',function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('episode_',''),
      width = 730,
      height = 645;

      if(id == 3){
        width = 635;
        height = 790;
      }                   

      ColdFusion.Window.create('Episode_'+id,'','/landing_pages/superhero/episode'+id+'.cfm',{width:width,height:height,center:true,draggable:false,resizable:false,modal:true});
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Michael Stone: Then your error is somewhere outside the code that you have shown. That code simply can not produce that error on itself.